# editText.getText().toString() in TextWatcher returns empty string at the first textchange

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I added a `textchangelistener` to my `Edittext` in which i check if the text is empty or not. When the text isn't empty and I press on the backspace key, all the text disappears and reappears again. This only occur the first time when backspace is pressed. After that it works like it should.

Using Editable s.toString() doesn't solve the issue.

What is causing this issue?

See the comments in the code for more information:

```
TextWatcher textwatcher = getMandatoryTextWatcher(editText);
String text = editText.getText().toString();//At this point String text is not empty.

editText.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);

public TextWatcher getMandatoryTextWatcher(final EditText editText) {
    TextWatcher textwatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                //The first time this is called(the first softkey backspace press),
                //text is empty. This causes a weird issue where the character that 
                //was just removed by pressing the backspace, reappears again. 
                //This is only the first time.

                String text = editText.getText().toString();

                if (text.length() <= 0) {
                    editText.setError(errorMandatory);

                } else if (text.length() > 0) {
                    editText.setError(null);
                } else {
                    editText.setError(errorMelding);
                }
           } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    editText.setError(errorMeldingTijdensParsen);
        }
    }
};
return textwatcher;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ohk dude just give this validation one first time

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Stringname))
{
   paste your rest code here 
}
```

so whenever its first time it will not going in the condition

Answer (score 0):

copy your code into `onTextChanged` and put your code into following if statement:

```
  if (s.length() > 0)
  {
    // do what you want
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use `s.toString();` instead of `editText.getText().toString();`

Comment: Exact same issue with s.toString().

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled your code for min. sdk 10 (2.3.3) and target sdk 14 (4.0).
Running it in a Samsung GT-P6800 device the reported behaviour does not occur.
Your problem may be outside the code. Try to run your code in another device.